# Reindex pandas dataframe based on uneven dates and then groupby and blank fill certain values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

df

```
Name    date          season  binary
Apple   2016-04-24    MAM     1
Banana  2016-05-01    MAM     1
Berry   2016-05-01    MAM     1
Berry   2017-11-05    OND     1
Orange  2016-11-27    OND     1
Kiwi    2017-03-27    MAM     1
```

And I have a long date time object of a bunch of dates like this:

df1

```
date        season  Week
2016-03-28  MAM     13
2016-04-04  MAM     14
2016-04-11  MAM     15
2016-04-18  MAM     16
2016-04-25  MAM     17
2016-05-02  MAM     18
2016-05-09  MAM     19
2016-05-16  MAM     20
2016-05-23  MAM     21
2016-05-30  MAM     22
2016-06-06  MAM     23
2016-06-13  MAM     24
2016-10-03  OND     40
2016-10-10  OND     41
2016-10-17  OND     42
2016-10-24  OND     43
2016-10-31  OND     44
2016-11-07  OND     45
2016-11-14  OND     46
2016-11-21  OND     47
2017-03-13  MAM     11
2017-03-20  MAM     12
2017-03-27  MAM     13
2017-04-03  MAM     14
2017-04-10  MAM     15
2017-04-17  MAM     16
2017-04-24  MAM     17
2017-05-01  MAM     18
2017-05-08  MAM     19
2017-05-15  MAM     20
2017-05-22  MAM     21
2017-05-29  MAM     22
2017-06-19  MAM     25
2017-06-26  MAM     26
2017-07-03  MAM     27
2017-07-10  MAM     28
2017-07-17  MAM     29
2017-07-24  MAM     30
2017-07-31  MAM     31
2017-08-07  MAM     32
2017-08-14  MAM     33
2017-08-21  MAM     34
2017-08-28  MAM     35
2017-09-04  MAM     36
2017-09-11  MAM     37
2017-09-18  MAM     38
2017-09-25  MAM     39
2017-10-02  OND     40
2017-10-09  OND     41
2017-10-16  OND     42
2017-10-23  OND     43
2017-10-30  OND     44
2017-11-06  OND     45
2017-11-13  OND     46
2017-11-20  OND     47
```

where `Week` is dtype: object, `date` is dtype: datetime64[ns], and `season` is dtype: object.

What I need is a bit complicated. I need a function or algorithm that recognizes `df.date` as the "end date" and `df1.date` as the "start date" for certain seasons. In other words, an event for "Apple" in `df` started on 2016-04-24 which is indicated by the `binary=1`. In a new dataframe, I need to include the weeks before 2016-04-24 but after 2016-03-28 and add a column that says `binary=0` because the event had not occurred yet.

The messy thing is that there a four seasons: MAM 2016, OND 2016, MAM 2017, and OND 2017. And the "start date" for each `df.date` should only be considered for that season.

As an example, this is what I'm looking to get:

df_result

```
Name    date          season  binary
Apple   2016-03-28    MAM     0
Apple   2016-04-04    MAM     0
Apple   2016-04-11    MAM     0
Apple   2016-04-18    MAM     0
Apple   2016-04-24    MAM     1
Banana  2016-03-28    MAM     0
Banana  2016-04-04    MAM     0
Banana  2016-04-11    MAM     0
Banana  2016-04-18    MAM     0
Banana  2016-04-25    MAM     0
Banana  2016-05-01    MAM     1
Berry   2016-03-28    MAM     0
Berry   2016-04-04    MAM     0
Berry   2016-04-11    MAM     0
Berry   2016-04-18    MAM     0
Berry   2016-04-25    MAM     0
Berry   2016-05-01    MAM     1
Berry   2017-10-02    OND     0
Berry   2017-10-09    OND     0
Berry   2017-10-16    OND     0
Berry   2017-10-23    OND     0
Berry   2017-10-30    OND     0
Berry   2017-11-05    OND     1
Orange  2016-10-03    OND     0
Orange  2016-10-10    OND     0
Orange  2016-10-17    OND     0
Orange  2016-10-24    OND     0
Orange  2016-10-31    OND     0
Orange  2016-11-07    OND     0
Orange  2016-11-14    OND     0
Orange  2016-11-21    OND     0
Orange  2016-11-27    OND     1
Kiwi    2017-03-13    MAM     0
Kiwi    2017-03-20    MAM     0
Kiwi    2017-03-27    MAM     1
```

To summarize the seasons in `start_end_dates` and make it a little clearer, these are the dates:

- MAM 2016: 2016-03-28 to 2016-06-13
- OND 2016: 2016-10-03 to 2016-11-21
- MAM 2017: 2017-03-13 to 2017-09-25
- OND 2017: 2017-10-02 to 2017-11-20

With some help, I know that this I should reindex `df` with something like `df2 = df.reindex(start_end_dates)` but this doesn't work out quite right.

Then I should groupby the names and blank fill with "0" the weeks before `df.date`. So maybe: `df3 = df3.loc[df3.groupby(level=0).binary.bfill().dropna().index].fillna(0).reset_index()`

I have seen this stack overflow question but it doesn't exactly answer my question: [Reindex pandas DataFrame to fill missing dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145276/reindex-pandas-dataframe-to-fill-missing-dates)

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: why kiwi only have two row , should it be more ?

Comment: You're right. Kiwi should have three rows. I will edit the question. @Wen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We using `merge_asof`

```
df['Year']=df['date'].dt.year
df1['Year']=df1['date'].dt.year
A=[]
for x in range(len(df)):
    Temp=pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('date'),df.sort_values('date').iloc[[x],:],on='date',by=['Year','season'],direction='forward',allow_exact_matches =False).dropna().drop('Week',1)
    Temp.binary=np.nan
    A.append(Temp)
A.append(df)
target=pd.concat(A).sort_values(['Name','date'])


target
Out[262]: 
      Name  Year  binary       date season
0    Apple  2016     NaN 2016-03-28    MAM
1    Apple  2016     NaN 2016-04-04    MAM
2    Apple  2016     NaN 2016-04-11    MAM
3    Apple  2016     NaN 2016-04-18    MAM
0    Apple  2016     1.0 2016-04-24    MAM
0   Banana  2016     NaN 2016-03-28    MAM
1   Banana  2016     NaN 2016-04-04    MAM
2   Banana  2016     NaN 2016-04-11    MAM
3   Banana  2016     NaN 2016-04-18    MAM
4   Banana  2016     NaN 2016-04-25    MAM
1   Banana  2016     1.0 2016-05-01    MAM
0    Berry  2016     NaN 2016-03-28    MAM
1    Berry  2016     NaN 2016-04-04    MAM
2    Berry  2016     NaN 2016-04-11    MAM
3    Berry  2016     NaN 2016-04-18    MAM
4    Berry  2016     NaN 2016-04-25    MAM
2    Berry  2016     1.0 2016-05-01    MAM
47   Berry  2017     NaN 2017-10-02    OND
48   Berry  2017     NaN 2017-10-09    OND
49   Berry  2017     NaN 2017-10-16    OND
50   Berry  2017     NaN 2017-10-23    OND
51   Berry  2017     NaN 2017-10-30    OND
3    Berry  2017     1.0 2017-11-05    OND
20    Kiwi  2017     NaN 2017-03-13    MAM
21    Kiwi  2017     NaN 2017-03-20    MAM
5     Kiwi  2017     1.0 2017-03-27    MAM
12  Orange  2016     NaN 2016-10-03    OND
13  Orange  2016     NaN 2016-10-10    OND
14  Orange  2016     NaN 2016-10-17    OND
15  Orange  2016     NaN 2016-10-24    OND
16  Orange  2016     NaN 2016-10-31    OND
17  Orange  2016     NaN 2016-11-07    OND
18  Orange  2016     NaN 2016-11-14    OND
19  Orange  2016     NaN 2016-11-21    OND
4   Orange  2016     1.0 2016-11-27    OND
```

Comment: Great! Thanks so much.

Comment: @JAG2024 Yw~ , happy coding, PS: do not getting scared by using for loop , some time it is faster than apply :-)